# ASP.NET MVC AngularJS page returning Model object

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 AngularJS(1.5.6) Application.

I have a MVC controller Action method that returns model object and bind that data to $scope variable.

**Here is the code:**

**Model Class:**

```
public class ApiurlAndUser
{
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action Method:**

```
public ApiurlAndUser GetApiurlAndUsername()
    {
        var data = new ApiurlAndUser();
        data.ApiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUrl"].ToString();
        var request = Request;
        if (request != null)
        {
            var userIdentity = ((System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper)request).LogonUserIdentity;
            if(userIdentity!=null)
                data.UserName = userIdentity.Name;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

**AngularJS Code in app.js file:**

```
vm.getApidomainAndUsername = function () {
            var url = vm.localUrl + 'home/GetApiurlAndUsername';
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function (result) {
                debugger;
                if (result.data.length > 0) {
                    var output = result.data;
                    $scope.userName = result.data.UserName;  //here it says undefined
                    $scope.apiDomain = result.data.ApiUrl;
                }
                else {
                    vm.g3pUserName = 'InvalidUser';
                }
            }, function (error) {
            });
        };
        vm.getApidomainAndUsername();
```

Here result.data is not null. It is showing that Model fullname. But how to access those values here? How to convert?
Appreciate your response.

Thanks
Rita

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without knowing what is in your result.data. 
I am guessing maybe you need to

```
var output = JSON.parse(result.data);
$scope.Username = output.UserName;
```